# RabbitMQ client can't connect to remote RabbitMQ server

Tags: connection, rabbitmq, remote-access

I have  a nodejs client that uses bramqp for connecting to RabbitMQ server. My client can connect to a Rabbit MQ server in localhost and works well. But it's unable to connect to a remote RabbitMQ server on other machine. I opened port 5672 in the remote server, so I think that the problem is in the configuration of rabbitMQ server. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which rabbitmq version ? are you using guest guest?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem seems the new [rabbitmq access control policy](http://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html)

Please read this post:
[Can't access RabbitMQ web management interface after fresh install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install/22854222#22854222)

I think it can help you!

Comment: None of those links helped me. Updating loopback_users or creating a separate admin user still results in the same error. RabbitMQ refuses all non-local connections.

Comment: @Cerin this is not a good reason to vote down, maybe you have some other problem. Did you check the log?

Comment: @Cerin FYI I ran into the same thing (i.e. created new non-guest user but still couldn't log in with non-guest user). As per Gabriele's suggestion, I checked the rabbitmq sasl log (Simple Authentication and Security Layer) and saw that each log in was being shown as "guest". I tried doing firefox "private mode" with the new user and was successful. I went back to the regular firefox and did a "clear recent history" and made sure to "clear active logins". After this I was able to log into the management web-ui remotely.

Comment: for all who didn't found the solution use following steps

rabbitmqctl add_user test test

rabbitmqctl set_user_tags test administrator

rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / test ".*" ".*" ".*"