# Why can I not open rabbitmq management console

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed rabbitmq-server on ubuntu vps server , then I have enabled  rabbitmq_management plugin. After that , When I try to open  the management console ( `http://<vps server ip> :15672)` , browser cannot  open the page.

I have looked the open port  on server, There are open port  whose number is 15672

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Unfortunetly , I can not  find the problem.
Thanks for your helping

Comment: Can you please specify at least RabbitMQ version?

Comment: It might be the same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install

Comment: version is 3.3.1. and ubuntu version is 14.04.

Comment: Check also your firewall configuration! the problem could be the network.

Comment: (looks trivial) make sure you have restarted rabbitmq daemon after enabling management plugin

Comment: thanks, I restarted rabbitmq deamon , then the problem is solved  , very thank your helping

Comment: I get the same on localhost (Ubuntu 14.04, RabbitMQ 3.2.4), WTF?

Answer (score 3):

Restart rabbitmq service, and try again.

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server restart
```