# RabbitMQ guest login failed in Linux

Tags: rabbitmq

We have installed RabbitMQ and Erlang on Linux but we are getting login failed exception when we are trying to login with guest/guest credentials. Can anyone explain why this issue is coming and Please let me know how to uninstall new erlang and RabbitMQ in the same machine as we are not able to uninstall the rabbitmq.

Comment: Pelase read this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install

Comment: Thanks.. I have created rabbit.config file with [{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}] entry. Its working fine.

Answer (score 5):

We need to create rabbit.config file with [{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}]. entry. Its working fine.

Comment: Unrelated: you are allowed to accept self-answers as well. Btw: thanks for keeping that question around. and as said, compensating a bit.