# Not able to connect Master RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I'm facing issue during connecting remote(Master)RabbitMQ.Here is my code snippet,

Con-fig:

```
            'MASTER': '127.0.0.1:8000',
            'WORKER_USER': 'test',
            'broker': 'amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672',
            'backend': 'amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672'
```

Code:

```
celery_config = config.get_worker_config()
celery = Celery('testtasks',
                broker=celery_config['broker'],
                backend=celery_config['backend'],
                include=['tasks'])
```

When the processing time, I'm getting this issue,

consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest@master:5672//: timed out.
Trying again in 32.00 seconds...

Help me to solve this issue.Thanks in Advance!

**[EDIT: After issue Solved]**

Thanks All

Issue Solved By rebooting the Master instance.But i need bit more explanation here? Please can any one know the root cause?

Comment: Read here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install

It could be an security problem

Comment: Also check firewall rules.

Comment: @zaq178miami,Issue Solved By rebooting the Master instance.But i need bit more explanation here? Please can any one know the root cause?