# rabbitmq not working with java

Tags: java, python, rabbitmq

I have rabbitmq setup on my machine and it has 3 different queues. One java code is listening to a queue and other queues are sending messages to python codes. Now python codes are working fine but java code seems to have a problem with AMQ. Following error is coming:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.rabbitmq.client.PossibleAuthenticationFailureException: Possibly caused by authentication failure
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:341)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:590)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:612)
    at com.elki.test.Worker.main(Worker.java:73)
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:343)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:216)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:202)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:326)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:290)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

How come there could be an `AuthenticationFailure` with java but not with python.
Any help appreciated.

CODE:

```
public static void main(String[] argv)
                          throws java.io.IOException,
                          java.lang.InterruptedException {

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("127.0.0.1");
        factory.setPort(5672);
        com.rabbitmq.client.Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

        channel.basicQos(1);

        QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
        channel.basicConsume(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, false, consumer);

        while (true) {
          QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
          String message = new String(delivery.getBody());

          System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");



          "do some work"
        System.out.println(" [x] Done" );

          int prefetchCount = 1;
          channel.basicQos(prefetchCount);
          channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
        }
      }
```

Comment: We need to see your code to be able to help.

Comment: @kviiri edited my question with code snippet

Comment: Did you change guest/quest permission? by default the client use guest/guest.

read also this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's because you haven't set the *password* nor the *username* on the `ConnectionFactory` object, and so it can't authenticate with *RabbitMQ*. (Perhaps your *Python* code is passing those in, and so therefore can authenticate.)

Try adding this code before calling `factory.newConnection`:

```
factory.setUsername(userName);
factory.setPassword(password);
```

replacing `userName` and `password` as needed for your code.

Comment: Actually, by default java-client uses guest/guest.

Comment: @Ken Python code is also not passing any username or password.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error. The problem was that the rabbitmq was started with default config on ipv6 protocol. I don't know why, but it does not work on windows linux subsystem.

Force ipv4 helped for me:

```
cat /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config

[
  {rabbit, [
    {tcp_listeners, [{"127.0.0.1", 5672}]}
  ]}
].
```

By default rabbitmq uses ipv6 address `::1`.

PS^ You need to create config file if there are not exists.