# PossibleAutheticationFailureException:RabbitMQ Java

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have been looking into this issue on the web but could not come up with a solution for it.

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("10.3.x.x");
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
```

I get an exception at the last line. 10.3.x.x is the ip of my computer but if I change the it to "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" it works.

Comment: Duplicate with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the RMQ guest user can only connect over the loopback interface (localhost). If you want to allow connections from remote hosts (which includes using your own IP even if you're on the same machine), you need to change the loopback_users configuration.

This is clearly described here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Answer (score 0):

OK I also solved this issue, previous versions were working fine without providing credentials, you didn't needed to create a user. With newer RabbitMQ installations you have to mention the username and password. 
This is also suggested by Dave Morrissey.