# rabbitmq 3.3.4 shovel configuration is crashing start process

Tags: configuration, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

I'm trying to configure the shovel plugin via the config file (running in docker) but I get this error:

```
  BOOT FAILED
  ===========

  Error description:
   {error,{failed_to_cluster_with,[rabbit@dalmacpmfd57],
                              "Mnesia could not connect to any nodes."}}
```

The config is set up this way because the destination for shovel will be created on demand when a dev environment is spun up... the source is a permanent rabbitmq instance running that the new, dev environment will attach to.

Here is the config file contents:

```
  [   
   {rabbitmq_shovel,
    [{shovels,
        [{indexer_replica_static,
           [{sources, 
                [{broker, [ "amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq/newdev" ]},
                       {declarations,
                            [{'queue.declare', [{queue,    <<"Indexer_Replica_Static">>}, durable]},
                             {'queue.bind',[ {exchange, <<"Indexer">>}, {queue, <<"Indexer_Replica_Static">>}]}
                            ]
                        }
                ]
            },
            {destinations, 
                [{broker, "amqp://"},
                      {declarations, [ {'exchange.declare', [ {exchange, <<"Indexer_Replica_Static">>}
                                     , {type, <<"fanout">>}, durable]},
                                     {'queue.declare', [
                                         {queue,    <<"Indexer_Replica_Static">>},
                                         durable]},
                                     {'queue.bind',
                                       [ {exchange, <<"Indexer_Replica_Static">>}
                                       , {queue,    <<"Indexer_Replica_Static">>}
                                       ]}
                                    ]
                       }
                ]
            },
           {queue, <<"Indexer_Replica_Static">>},
           {prefetch_count, 0},
           {ack_mode, on_confirm},
           {publish_properties, [ {delivery_mode, 2} ]},
           {reconnect_delay, 2.5}
           ]
        }
        ]
      },
      {reconnect_delay,    2.5}
    ]
  }
 ].
```

[UPDATE]
This is being run in docker but since I couldn't debug the issue in docker I tried booting up rabbit locally with the same config file. I noticed in the logs that the rabbit config system variable I set (RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE) isn't reflected in the log and the shovel settings haven't been applied (no surprise huh). I verified the variable with an echo statement and the correct path is displayed: /dev/rabbitmq_server-3.3.4/rabbitmq

```
  =INFO REPORT==== 3-Sep-2014::15:30:37 ===
  node           : rabbit@dalmacpmfd57
  home dir       : /Users/e002678
  config file(s) : (none)
  cookie hash    : n6vhh8tY7Z+uR2DV6gcHUg==
  log            : /usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.3.4/sbin/../var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@dalmacpmfd57.log
  sasl log       : /usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.3.4/sbin/../var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@dalmacpmfd57-   sasl.log
  database dir   : /usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.3.4/sbin/../var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@dalmacpmfd57
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you enable the guest:guest access?

Comment: @Gas No, I haven't. I thought guest was automatically enabled. Before trying to enable the shovel config I was able to log into the management web interface with guest. I'll look that up thanks!

Comment: @Gas from what I can tell from the doco guest is automatically enabled as an admin. scary :-).

Comment: by default you can use "guest" only in localhost, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install 

Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Gas Hello. Thanks, I looked at the above mentioned link and don't understand how that would apply in my case. For now, I'm trying to access rabbit via localhost. Also, I haven't fixed the issue (same error as originally reported). Thank!