# rabbitMQ Connection timed out

Tags: java, rabbitmq, virtual-machine

I have rabbitMQ server running on vm.
I am following rabbitMQ java tutorial.
It works fine locally on the vm but when trying to send from the host I get an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:32)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:714)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:760)
at Send.main(Send.java:16)
```

here is the send code i am using:

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

public class Send {
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException, TimeoutException {

            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.setHost("192.168.198.100");
            factory.setPort(5672);
            Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
            Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

            channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
            String message = "Hello World from Windows!";
            channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
            System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");

            channel.close();
            connection.close();

        }
    }
```

I can ping the server at 192.168.198.100 but I can't access the managment UI at
192.168.198.100:15672/

So could anyone help me figure out what's wrong with this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.

You are using `guest` `guest` as credentials, and it is not allowed for remote IP.

Please read this: [Can't access RabbitMQ web management interface after fresh install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install)
then you have to add this:

```
factory.setPassword("test");
factory.setUsername("test");
```

2.

Did you enable the management UI? if not use:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

3.

check your firewall configuration maybe the ports 5672 and 15672 are closed.
You can use `telnet` to test the ports:

```
telnet 192.168.198.100 5672
Trying 192.168.198.100...
Connected to 192.168.198.100.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

and:

```
telnet 192.168.198.100 15672
Trying 192.168.198.100...
Connected to 192.168.198.100.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: Thank you actually the firewall ports of the server was closed.