# Connection failing between Raspberry Pi and Mac

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

I have the following

a) a rabbitmq-server and Pika installed on a Mac Yosrmite machine.
I have a rabbutmq.config  /usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config that I have the statement:
{loopback_users, []}

b) On the raspberry pi I have pika installed. I also installed the rabbtmq-server.

The send.py and receive.py, using pika, work locally on both machines.

## The send from the Mac to the RPi works; but, the send from the RPi to the Mac fails as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send.py", line 5, in 
    '192.168.1.4'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 339, in **init**
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 374, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 395, in _flush_output
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed

========================================
My firewall is not enabled in the Mac.
There is no errors noted in the server log.

The send.py code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
               '192.168.1.4'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body='Hello World!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")

connection.close()
```

===========================
I am getting the activity on the port, in both machines:
sudo tcpdump port 5672

On RPi
15:09:05.394815 IP raspberrypi.home.40483 > ArnoldBileysMBP.home.amqp: Flags [S], seq 1428528534, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1626318 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
15:09:05.460755 IP ArnoldBileysMBP.home.amqp > raspberrypi.home.40483: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1428528535, win 0, length 0

On Mac
11:09:05.547322 IP raspberrypi.home.40483 > arnoldbileysmbp.home.amqp: Flags [S], seq 1428528534, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1626318 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
11:09:05.547362 IP arnoldbileysmbp.home.amqp > raspberrypi.home.40483: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1428528535, win 0, length 0

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173246/rabbitmq-connection-timed-out

Comment: Thanks Gabriele,
I added the test/test admin as suggested and the ensuring the enabling of the gui. I changed the connection statement to:

    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('test', 'test')

    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
               "192.168.1.4", 5672,  '/', credentials))

 I always could send from the mac to the rpi using the server on the rpi. I don't have telnet to mac on the rpi to test..  But, I do see, as shown above in the tcpdump, a send on the port of the rpi and a corresponding receipt on the mac. I still failed, as above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix at [Open port 5672/tcp for access to RabbitMQ on Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/464311/open-port-5672-tcp-for-access-to-rabbitmq-on-mac)
I deleted the "NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
" statement in the /usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf fiile. This was in addition to the above fix I made to the accessing.