# Cannot connect with RabbitMQ using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, rabbitmq

I am starting using RabbitMQ with Swift. I had followed the example code from the library for RabbitMQ on [github](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client):

```
let delegate = RMQConnectionDelegateLogger() 
let conn = RMQConnection(uri: "amqp://localhost:5672", delegate: delegate)

conn.start()

let ch = conn.createChannel()

let q = ch.queue("hello")
q.subscribe { rm in
    print(rm.content )
}
```

And I get a lot of times these errors:

> Will start recovery for connection: <'
>   Received connection: <'RMQConnection: 0x7fdb43c73670> disconnectedWithError: Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}RMQConnection: 0x7fdb43c73670>

And on the RabbitMQ log I got this error:

> Error on AMQP connection <0.271.0> (172.19.0.1:53144 -> 172.19.0.4:5672, state: starting):
>   PLAIN login refused: user '' - invalid credentials

Where can I define the credentials? I had searching a lot for an example and I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

check this:

[Can't access RabbitMQ web management interface after fresh install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install/22854222#22854222)

and after that change the URL connection as:

```
'amqp://test:test@localhost:5672/'
```