# RabbitMQ Shovel, got error message: auth_failure,"ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN

Tags: rabbitmq

I've one cluster with two rabbitmq nodes host on two linux server. I expect to set first dynamic shovel to route message from node1's 'SourceQueue' to nodes2's 'DestinationQueue'.

So I use rabbitmq-plugins command to enabled rabbitmq_shovel and rabbitmq_shovel_management plugins on both nodes, then the shovel status and shovel management menus can be found from the RMQ web management according to the web browser.

But when I was trying to add a new sholve named 'FirstShovel' from the RMQ management website, I got the error message below.

**auth_failure,"ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication
mechanism PLAIN.**

[shovel creation snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJO64.png)

and the status of 'FirstShovel' was terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to specify user name and password on you amqp connection:

for example:

```
amqp://user:pass@host:5672
```

In you case, you are using `guest guest` as user name and password.

guest guest is allowed only in localhost.

see for example:[Can't access RabbitMQ web management interface after fresh install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install)

Comment: many thanks for your help. BTW, if I've a enterprise cluster and team cluster on uat env, and each cluster including two RMQ nodes. If I expect to route message from SourceMessage queue on enterprise cluster to DestinationQueue on TeamCluster, how can I do to set a shovel? Is that right to set a shovel just on one of the enterprise node?