# HTTP headers and values for accessing localhost

Tags: telerik, http-headers, rabbitmq

[image]

I'm trying to integrate my application to RabbitMQ. I want to send a request to my localhost, so what should be the HTTP header and its value?

Do I need a username and password to access localhost via a HTTP request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you have to add username and password:

Suppose to have username and pwd as [`test` `test`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install/22854222#22854222) it will be:

1. Create queue:

   `curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"auto_delete":false,"durable":true,"arguments":[]}' -u test:test http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2f/my_queue`
2. publish a message to a queue:

   `curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"properties":{"delivery_mode":2}, "routing_key":"my_queue","payload":"message test ","payload_encoding":"string"}' -u test:test http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2f/amq.default/publish`
3. get the queues:

   `curl -X GET -u test:test http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2F`

[Here](https://raw.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_6/priv/www/api/index.html) all the API

you need to add `authorization` as : 
[image: http header]

Comment: This is to be done from the rabbitmq side but what should i enter in this http header and header value field ?

Comment: @Nerdal added an image, it should help you

Comment: I've got no such autherization options when i go to the following site-

Comment: {"error":"not_authorised","reason":"Login failed"}

message delivered when I run the above codes provided by you on curl

Comment: Did you add the user test test ? Or you can use guest guest as credential

Comment: I had tried both test:test and guest:guest
with guest i get this error -

{"error":"bad_request","reason":"not_json"}

Comment: There is an access credential problem, try to login to the UI using the credential an see if it works.

Comment: Yes with guest it works properly. I'm able to use the UI.

Comment: My api still says connection refused. I'm not able to access rabbitmq and not able to send http get request to the localhost.