# RabbitMq SocketException connecting to remote server works despite exceptions

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ 3.6.5, Erlang 19.0 and having a strange issue regarding exceptions

```
  var factory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            HostName = _hostName,
            UserName = _uname,
            Password = _pwd,
            AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true
        };
        _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
```

throws two exceptions

-SocketException "The requested address is not valid in its context"

-ConnectionFailure Exception "RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException' in RabbitMQ.Client.dll

Additional information: Connection failed"

**simply changing the exception settings to not break execution solves the issue , (code does not stop execution) and the RabbitMQ connections work great.**

Not sure how to get rid of these exceptions any help is appreciated. Iam hoping someone has encountered a similar issue as i don't know how I can provide steps to replicate this issue.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The listening address you have specified is invalid for some reason.

Note that you cant use `guest` `guest` as user name and password for no localhost ip(s).

Read this [Can't access RabbitMQ web management interface after fresh install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install)

be sure to use only the ip in your ip as:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "192.168.1.13" };
```