# Cannot connect to amqp://user:**@ip-11-222-12-117:5672//: Couldn't log in: a socket error occurred

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, celery, airflow

I am trying to scale airflow using celery and rabbitMq on EC2.

I am following following code:
http://site.clairvoyantsoft.com/setting-apache-airflow-cluster/

Following is code in master node.

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://user:gues@localhost:5432/airflow
executor = CeleryExecutor
broker_url = amqp://user:gues@ip-11-222-12-117:5672
celery_result_backend = db+postgresql://user:gues@localhost:5432/airflow
```

Following is code for salve node:

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://user:gues@ip-11-222-12-117:5432/airflow
executor = CeleryExecutor
broker_url = amqp://user:gues@ip-11-222-12-117:5672
celery_result_backend = db+postgresql://user:gues@localhost:5432/airflow
```

When I run `airflow scheduler`, it works fine. But on slave node I am getting following error:

```
[2017-05-23 21:47:44,385: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://user:**@ip-11-222-12-117:5672//: Couldn't log in: a socket error occurred.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds..
```

However I am able to see both nodes connected using rabbitMq on rabbitMQ UI.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that the amqp server is allowed to listen to anything other than the loopback? Please check this answer: [Can't access RabbitMQ web management interface after fresh install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install/22854222#22854222)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to provide permission as follows rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / test ".*" ".*" ".*"