# RabbitMq On Ubuntu:Cannot acess RabbitMq Web management console

Tags: rabbitmq, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed rabbitmq-server on ubuntu , post installation I have checked if its running properly on the ports or not using `netstat -lntu`. Its running, plugins are enabled and same has been verified too. Even port 15672 is also open. What can be the reason that I am not able to acces web management console from the remote rabbitmq-server.

P.S : I have already created the admin user.

I have already tried allowing the port 15672 as mentioned in this question : [How do I find my firewall is blocking mysql? | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174646/how-do-i-find-my-firewall-is-blocking-mysql). and also followed this one : [Can't access RabbitMQ web management interface after fresh install | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install) and many more.

and lastly tried to edit `rabbitmq-env.conf` as suggested here : [Web dispatch plugin | RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-dispatch.html).

Comment: You need to provide the RabbitMQ and Erlang version. Please provide the commands you ran to install RabbitMQ as well as diagnose this issue, and provide the command output. What is the output when you run this command on the server - `curl -4vvv -u guest:guest localhost:15672/api/overview`

Comment: service rabbitmq-server start rabbitmq version 3.7.3 erlang - 19.3

Comment: Please provide the commands you ran to install RabbitMQ as well as diagnose this issue, and provide the command output. What is the output when you run this command on the server - `curl -4vvv -u guest:guest localhost:15672/api/overview`. Finally, you may get more responses if you post this question with the information I requested to the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users).

Answer (score 1):

By default, RabbitMQ creates a user named **"guest"** with password **"guest”**. You can also create your own administrator account on RabbitMQ server using following commands. Change password to your own password.

> **Step 1:** Set the username and password by running the following commands

- `sudo rabbitmqctl add_user admin password`
- `sudo rabbitmqctl set_user_tags admin administrator`
- `sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / admin ".*" ".*" ".*"`

> **Step 2**: Enable and use the RabbitMQ management console

- `sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`
- `sudo chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/`

Next, you need to setup an administrator user account for accessing the RabbitMQ server management console. In the following commands, "**mqadmin**" is the administrator's username, "**mqadminpassword**" is the password. Remember to replace them with your own.

> **Step 3:**: Add user and give the permission

- `sudo rabbitmqctl add_user mqadmin mqadminpassword`
- `sudo rabbitmqctl set_user_tags mqadmin administrator`
- `sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / mqadmin ".*" ".*" ".*"`

> Now open the http://[rabbitMQ-server-IP]:15672/ and You are Done

Answer (score 1):

For rabbitmq setup only need to do following things

1.install rabbitmq-server

> sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server

2.enable gui plugin

> sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

3.start rabbidmq-server

> sudo rabbitmq-server start

4.see gui on browser(bellow information is given by default rabbitmq configuration)

> http://localhost:15672/
>
> username:guest
>
> password:guest